# Connection between subspaces of matrices and their vectorized versions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$, $M>N$, be a full-column-rank matrix. A vectorized version of $\mathbf{A}$ can be obtained as $\mathbf{b} = \text{vec}(\mathbf{A}) \in \mathbb{R}^{MN}$ by stacking the columns of $\mathbf{A}$ in a vector form.

Now, define:

-$\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A})$ as the column span or range of $\mathbf{A}$;

-$\mathbb{A}\subset\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$ as the set of $M\times N$ matrices satisfying $\mathbf{A}_i\in\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A}), \forall i=1,\cdots M$, where $\mathbf{A}_i$ is the $i$-th column;

-$\mathbb{B}\subset\mathbb{R}^{MN}$ as the set of $MN\times 1$ vectorized versions of all the matrices in $\mathbb{A}$.

**My question is:**

What is the connection between the two subspaces occupied by the elements of $\mathbb{A}$ and $\mathbb{B}$? Are there any results related to this connection (Apparently my search did not return anything to note).

**Big Picture:**

I am trying to characterize the intersection of a hypersphere centered at a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and the set of matrices of the same size, whose columns are in the range of $\mathbf{A}$. I thought it is a good idea to work in the vector space.

Comment: In what metric are you taking the hypersphere? Matrices with the same range form a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$, $N^2$-dimensional, their columns are just linear combinations of the columns of $\mathbf{A}$. So if the metric comes from the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) then the intersection is just an $N^2-1$-dimensional hypersphere. If not, I am not sure how vectorization is supposed to help since it destroys the relevant structure that defines the spectral norm, for example.

Comment: Thank you, Conifold. Of course, I am considering the Frobenius norm as the distance metric. I am not sure why the intersection is $(N^2-1)-$dimensional, though.  Clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have $N$ columns, and you can put linear combinations of $N$ columns from $\mathbf{A}$ into each, so $N^2$ parameters (their coefficients) since $\mathbf{A}$ is full rank. Intersection of a Euclidean sphere with a subspace is a sphere in it, and has one dimension less than the subspace.

Comment: I see...That's really helpful. What if we consider the intersection of a Hyperspherical  surface instead of a whole hypersphere? Will we end up in an $(N^2-2)$-dimensional space?

Comment: Hypersphere is the "surface" only. The interior is called hyperball, it has the same dimension as the space it is in.

Comment: Many thanks! I wasn't aware of the terminology difference.